# stay in debug mode when switching to another app using android studio

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-activity

My problem is that I have a bug somewhere in my code but only happens when i switch to another app(let's say chrome) and return to my app. every time i return to my app, the activity crashes and it redirects me to the previous activity in my app.i want somehow to stay in debug mode after switching to another app. Is it possible to do it in android studio?

Comment: Some [background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) info.

Comment: @JeroenHeier thanks for the answer.